# PL SQL Retrieve Table data to XML TYPE

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex, appendchild, xmltype

I wanted to know why my data is not filter in 3rd level by 2nd level primary key.
In first level i'm passing Item Id as a PREFNO then after i'm retrieving data according to ITEM_ID. 2nd level finding primary key of LEVEL_ID using ITEM_ID and retrieving Dimensions according to LEVEL_ID. But my Dimensions getting repeating its mean in filtering part is not working. when i run my Dimensions query along its not repeating. but adding the same query to en trier xmltype query its getting repeated

```
SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT ("UomDimensions",
       XMLFOREST ("DimensionId"      AS "DimensionId",
       "DimensionName"    AS "DimensionName",
       "DimensionValue"   AS "DimensionValue")))
       FROM (SELECT P.DIMENSION_ID    AS "DimensionId",
       P.DIMENSION_DESC  AS "DimensionName",
       0                 AS "DimensionValue"
       FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.DIMENSION_SETTINGS O, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.DIMENSIONS P
       WHERE P.DIMENSION_ID        = O.DIMENSION_ID
       AND O.SETTING_PROPERTY_ID   = 42
       AND O.SETTING_VALUE         = 1
       AND P.DIMENSION_ID NOT IN (
                                 SELECT P.DIMENSION_ID 
                                 FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.DIMENSIONS P, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVEL_DIMNSIONS Q, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVELS X, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS A
                                  WHERE A.ITEM_ID      = X.ITEM_ID
                                  AND   X.LEVEL_ID     = Q.LEVEL_ID
--                                AND   X.LEVEL_ID     = K.LEVEL_ID
                                  AND   Q.DIMENSION_ID = P.DIMENSION_ID
                                  AND   A.ITEM_ID      = PREF_NO )
                                  UNION 
                                  SELECT P.DIMENSION_ID      AS "DimensionId",
                                  P.DIMENSION_DESC    AS "DimensionName",
                                  Q.DIMENSION_VALUE   AS "DimensionValue"
                                  FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS A, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVELS Z, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.DIMENSIONS P, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVEL_DIMNSIONS Q
                                  WHERE A.ITEM_ID      = PREF_NO
                                  AND   A.ITEM_ID      = Z.ITEM_ID 
                                  AND   Q.DIMENSION_ID = P.DIMENSION_ID
--                                AND   Q.LEVEL_ID     = K.LEVEL_ID
                                   AND   Q.LEVEL_ID     = Z.LEVEL_ID))
```

This is my whole query

```
SELECT
   XMLELEMENT (             "OBJECT",
   XMLELEMENT (                       "Item",
   XMLFOREST( 1                    AS "LocationId",
   A.ITEM_ID            AS "Id",
   A.ITEM_ID            AS "ItemId",
   A.REMARKS            AS "Remarks",
   A.CODE               AS "ItemCode",
   A.NAME               AS "ItemDescription",
   A.SHORT_NAME         AS "ItemShortName",
   A.HS_CODE_ID         AS "HsCodeId",
   B.HS_CODE            AS "HsCodeName",
   A.BRAND_ID           AS "ItemBrandId",
   C.BRAND_DESCRIPTION  AS "ItemBrandName",
   A.CAT_ID             AS "CategoryId",
   D.ITEM_CAT_DESC      AS "CategoryName",
   A.VARIANT_TEMP_ID    AS "VariantTemplateId",
   E.VARIANT_TEMP_NAME  AS "VarinatTemplateName",
   (SELECT
      XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT ("ItemUomLevels",
      XMLFOREST (K.UOM_LEVEL               AS "UomLevelId",
      K.UOM_ID                  AS "UomId",
      L.DESCRIPTION             AS "Uom",
      K.LONG_NAME               AS "UomLongName",
      K.CONV_FACTR              AS "ConversionFactor",
      K.STATUS_ID               AS "UomLevelStatus",
      K.SYS_USAGE_ID            AS "UomLevelSystemUsageTypeId",
      H.SYS_USAGE_NAME          AS "UomLevelSystemUsageType",
      K.IMAGE                   AS "UomLevelImage",
      K.UOM_LEVEL_VOLUME        AS "UomLevelVolume",
      (SELECT
         UNIQUE CASE  
            WHEN S.ITEM_ID<>0 THEN 1                                                                
         END AS "UomLevelEditable"                                                            
      FROM
         BIZZXE_V2_SCH.PO_REQUEST_ITEMS S 
      WHERE
         S.ITEM_Id = PREF_NO 
         AND S.UOM_ID= L.UOM_ID) AS "UomLevelEditable",
      (SELECT
         XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT ("UomDimensions",
         XMLFOREST ("DimensionId"      AS "DimensionId",
         "DimensionName"    AS "DimensionName",
         "DimensionValue"   AS "DimensionValue")))                                                               
      FROM
         (SELECT
            P.DIMENSION_ID    AS "DimensionId",
            P.DIMENSION_DESC  AS "DimensionName",
            0                 AS "DimensionValue"                                                                     
         FROM
            BIZZXE_V2_SCH.DIMENSION_SETTINGS O,
            BIZZXE_V2_SCH.DIMENSIONS P                                                                     
         WHERE
            P.DIMENSION_ID        = O.DIMENSION_ID                                                                     
            AND O.SETTING_PROPERTY_ID   = 42                                                                     
            AND O.SETTING_VALUE         = 1                                                                     
            AND P.DIMENSION_ID NOT IN (                                                                                               SELECT
               P.DIMENSION_ID                                                                                                
            FROM
               BIZZXE_V2_SCH.DIMENSIONS P,
               BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVEL_DIMNSIONS Q,
               BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVELS X,
               BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS A                                                                       
            WHERE
               A.ITEM_ID      = X.ITEM_ID                                                                       
               AND   X.LEVEL_ID     = Q.LEVEL_ID                                                                       
           --    AND   X.LEVEL_ID     = K.LEVEL_ID                                                                       
               AND   Q.DIMENSION_ID = P.DIMENSION_ID                                                                       
               AND   A.ITEM_ID      = PREF_NO )                                                                   
         UNION
         SELECT
            P.DIMENSION_ID      AS "DimensionId",
            P.DIMENSION_DESC    AS "DimensionName",
            Q.DIMENSION_VALUE   AS "DimensionValue"                                                                   
         FROM
            BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS A,
            BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVELS Z,
            BIZZXE_V2_SCH.DIMENSIONS P,
            BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVEL_DIMNSIONS Q                                                                   
         WHERE
            A.ITEM_ID      = PREF_NO                                                                   
            AND   A.ITEM_ID      = Z.ITEM_ID                                                                    
            AND   Q.DIMENSION_ID = P.DIMENSION_ID                                                                   
       --     AND   Q.LEVEL_ID     = K.LEVEL_ID                                                                   
            AND   Q.LEVEL_ID     = Z.LEVEL_ID )) AS "UomDimensionsList")))                                         
FROM
   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVELS K,
   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.UOMS L,
   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_SYSTEM_USAGES H                                         
WHERE
   A.ITEM_ID        = PREF_NO                                         
   AND   A.ITEM_ID        = K.ITEM_ID                                         
   AND   K.SYS_USAGE_ID   = H.SYS_USAGE_ID                                         
   AND   K.UOM_ID         = L.UOM_ID)AS "ItemUomLevelsList")))         
INTO
   varXml         
FROM
   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS A,
   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.HS_CODES B,
   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.BRANDS C,
   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_CATEGORIES D,
   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.VARIANT_TEMPLATES E      
WHERE
   A.ITEM_ID         = PREF_NO      
   AND   A.HS_CODE_ID      = B.HS_CODE_ID      
   AND   C.BRAND_ID        = A.BRAND_ID      
   AND   D.ITEM_CAT_ID     = A.CAT_ID      
   AND   A.VARIANT_TEMP_ID = E.VARIANT_TEMP_ID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT (
       "OBJECT", XMLELEMENT (
                 "Item", XMLFOREST( 1                    AS "LocationId",
                                    A.ITEM_ID            AS "Id",
                                    A.ITEM_ID            AS "ItemId",
                                    A.REMARKS            AS "Remarks",
                                    A.CODE               AS "ItemCode",
                                    A.NAME               AS "ItemDescription",
                                    A.SHORT_NAME         AS "ItemShortName",
                                    A.HS_CODE_ID         AS "HsCodeId",
                                    B.HS_CODE            AS "HsCodeName",
                                    A.BRAND_ID           AS "ItemBrandId",
                                    C.BRAND_DESCRIPTION  AS "ItemBrandName",
                                    A.CAT_ID             AS "CategoryId",
                                    D.ITEM_CAT_DESC      AS "CategoryName",
                                    A.VARIANT_TEMP_ID    AS "VariantTemplateId",
                                    E.VARIANT_TEMP_NAME  AS "VarinatTemplateName",
                                    (SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT ("AllocationTypes",
                                                  XMLFOREST ("AllocationTypeId"             AS "AllocationTypeId",
                                                             "AllocationValue"              AS "AllocationValue",
                                                             "AllocationType"               AS "AllocationType",
                                                             "AllocationSystemUsageTypeId"  AS "AllocationSystemUsageTypeId",
                                                             "AllocationSystemUsageType"    AS "AllocationSystemUsageType")))
                                     FROM  (SELECT 
                                                 F.ALLOCATION_ID        AS "AllocationTypeId",
                                                 F.VALUE                AS "AllocationValue",
                                                 G.ALLOCATION_DESC      AS "AllocationType",
                                                 F.SYS_USAGE_ID         AS "AllocationSystemUsageTypeId",
                                                 H.SYS_USAGE_NAME       AS "AllocationSystemUsageType"
                                           FROM  BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS A, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_ALLOCATIONS F, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ALLOCATIONS G, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_SYSTEM_USAGES H
                                           WHERE A.ITEM_ID       = F.ITEM_ID
                                           AND   A.ITEM_ID       = PREF_NO
                                           AND   F.SYS_USAGE_ID  = H.SYS_USAGE_ID
                                           AND   G.ALLOCATION_ID = F.ALLOCATION_ID

                                           UNION
                                           SELECT 
                                                 G.ALLOCATION_ID    AS "AllocationTypeId",
                                                 0                  AS "AllocationValue",
                                                 G.ALLOCATION_DESC  AS "AllocationType",
                                                 0                  AS "AllocationSystemUsageTypeId",
                                                 NULL               AS "AllocationSystemUsageType" 
                                           FROM  BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ALLOCATIONS G
                                           WHERE  G.ALLOCATION_ID NOT IN
                                                                     (SELECT G.ALLOCATION_ID        AS "AllocationTypeId"
                                                                     FROM  BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS A, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_ALLOCATIONS G
                                                                     WHERE A.ITEM_ID = G.ITEM_ID
                                                                     AND   A.ITEM_ID = PREF_NO)))AS "AllocationTypesList",
                                  (SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT ("VariantDimensionMatrix",
                                                  XMLFOREST ("SkuPrefixCode"            AS "SkuPrefixCode",
                                                             "SkuPrefixDescription"     AS "SkuPrefixDescription",
                                                             "ValidSku"                 AS "SkuSelected")))

                                     FROM
                                     ( SELECT
                                          I.SKU_PREFIX_CODE AS "SkuPrefixCode",
                                          I.SKU_DESCRIPTION AS "SkuPrefixDescription",
                                          '0'               AS "ValidSku"
                                    FROM  BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS  A, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.VARIANT_TEMP_DIMENSIONS I, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.VARIANT_TEMPLATES E
                                    WHERE I.VARIANT_TEMP_ID    = E.VARIANT_TEMP_ID
                                    AND   I.VARIANT_TEMP_ID    = A.VARIANT_TEMP_ID
                                    AND   A.ITEM_ID            = PREF_NO
                                    AND   I.SKU_PREFIX_CODE NOT IN
                                                         ( SELECT
                                                                 J.SKU_PREFIX_CODE AS "SkuPrefixCode"
                                                           FROM  BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS A, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_VARINTS J
                                                           WHERE A.ITEM_ID  = J.ITEM_ID
                                                           AND   A.ITEM_ID  = PREF_NO)
                                    UNION

                                    SELECT
                                          J.SKU_PREFIX_CODE   AS "SkuPrefixCode",
                                          J.SKU_PREFIX_DESC   AS "SkuPrefixDescription",
                                          J.VALID_SKU         AS "ValidSku"
                                    FROM  BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS A, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_VARINTS J
                                    WHERE A.ITEM_ID     = PREF_NO
                                    AND   A.ITEM_ID     = J.ITEM_ID))AS "VariantDimensionMatrixList",
                                    (SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT ("ItemUomLevels",
                                                  XMLFOREST (K.UOM_LEVEL               AS "UomLevelId",
                                                             K.UOM_ID                  AS "UomId",
                                                             L.DESCRIPTION             AS "Uom",
                                                             K.LONG_NAME               AS "UomLongName",
                                                             K.CONV_FACTR              AS "ConversionFactor",
                                                             K.STATUS_ID               AS "UomLevelStatus",
                                                             K.SYS_USAGE_ID            AS "UomLevelSystemUsageTypeId",
                                                             H.SYS_USAGE_NAME          AS "UomLevelSystemUsageType",
                                                             K.IMAGE                   AS "UomLevelImage",
                                                             K.UOM_LEVEL_VOLUME        AS "UomLevelVolume",
                                                      (SELECT
                                                         UNIQUE CASE  WHEN S.ITEM_ID<>0 THEN 1
                                                          END AS "UomLevelEditable"
                                                      FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.PO_REQUEST_ITEMS S WHERE S.ITEM_Id = PREF_NO AND S.UOM_ID= L.UOM_ID) AS "UomLevelEditable",

                                                            (SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT ("UomLevelControls",
                                                             XMLFOREST (M.CONTROL_ID   AS "ControlId",
                                                                        M.CONTROL_NAME AS "ControlName")))

                                                      FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS A, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.UOM_CONTROLS M, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVEL_CONTROLS N,BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVELS Y
                                                      WHERE A.ITEM_ID     = PREF_NO
                                                      AND   A.ITEM_ID     = K.ITEM_ID
                                                      AND   K.LEVEL_ID    = N.LEVEL_ID
                                                      AND   Y.LEVEL_ID    = N.LEVEL_ID 
                                                      AND   N.CONTROL_ID  = M.CONTROL_ID) AS "UomLevelControlsList",
                                                     (SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT ("UomDimensions",
                                                             XMLFOREST ("DimensionId"      AS "DimensionId",
                                                                        "DimensionName"    AS "DimensionName",
                                                                        "DimensionValue"   AS "DimensionValue",
                                                                        "Level"            AS "Level")))
                                                         FROM (SELECT P.DIMENSION_ID    AS "DimensionId",
                                                                      P.DIMENSION_DESC  AS "DimensionName",
                                                                      0                 AS "DimensionValue",
                                                                      0                 AS "Level"
                                                               FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.DIMENSION_SETTINGS O, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.DIMENSIONS P
                                                               WHERE P.DIMENSION_ID        = O.DIMENSION_ID
                                                               AND O.SETTING_PROPERTY_ID   = 42
                                                               AND O.SETTING_VALUE         = 1
                                                               AND P.DIMENSION_ID NOT IN (
                                                                                         SELECT P.DIMENSION_ID 
                                                                                         FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.DIMENSIONS P, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVEL_DIMNSIONS Q, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVELS X, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS A
                                                                 WHERE A.ITEM_ID      = X.ITEM_ID
                                                                 AND   X.LEVEL_ID     = Q.LEVEL_ID
                                                                 AND   A.ITEM_ID      = PREF_NO )
                                                             UNION 
                                                               SELECT P.DIMENSION_ID      AS "DimensionId",
                                                                      P.DIMENSION_DESC    AS "DimensionName",
                                                                      Q.DIMENSION_VALUE   AS "DimensionValue",
                                                                      Q.LEVEL_ID          AS "Level"
                                                             FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS A, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVELS Z, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.DIMENSIONS P, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVEL_DIMNSIONS Q
                                                             WHERE A.ITEM_ID      = PREF_NO
                                                             AND   A.ITEM_ID      = Z.ITEM_ID 
                                                             AND   Q.DIMENSION_ID = P.DIMENSION_ID
                                                             AND   Q.LEVEL_ID     = Z.LEVEL_ID) DUAL WHERE K.LEVEL_ID="Level") AS "UomDimensionsList")))
                                   FROM  BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVELS K, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.UOMS L, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_SYSTEM_USAGES H
                                   WHERE A.ITEM_ID        = PREF_NO
                                   AND   A.ITEM_ID        = K.ITEM_ID
                                   AND   K.SYS_USAGE_ID   = H.SYS_USAGE_ID
                                   AND   K.UOM_ID         = L.UOM_ID)AS "ItemUomLevelsList")))

INTO varXml

FROM  BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS A, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.HS_CODES B, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.BRANDS C, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_CATEGORIES D, BIZZXE_V2_SCH.VARIANT_TEMPLATES E
WHERE A.ITEM_ID         = PREF_NO
AND   A.HS_CODE_ID      = B.HS_CODE_ID
AND   C.BRAND_ID        = A.BRAND_ID
AND   D.ITEM_CAT_ID     = A.CAT_ID
AND   A.VARIANT_TEMP_ID = E.VARIANT_TEMP_ID;
```